# How to check if app has ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION and other storage permissions on lower Androids

Tags: java, android, permissions, manifest, android-11

Is there a way to check if my device already has the following permissions with one line or how should I check this?

I am supporting SDK versions from 21 to 30 so I cannot use :

```
if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
```

Because it requires API level 30, but my min is 21.

This is how I am asking for permissions:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        try {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    }
}
```

So is there a permission check that would work for all of these?

Comment: `if my device already has the following permissions` I see no following permissions..

Comment: `Because it requires API level 30, but my min is 21.` ?? Being able to compile that function does not depend on minimum version. You only should call that function for  build versions 30. Like you do with the settings. (Where it should be > Q)

Comment: `is there a permission check that would work for all of these?` ? Strange question. Permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is only for Android 11+ devices. So a check is only possible for Android 11+ devices

Comment: Well but how should you check if these permissions exist?

Comment: ????? I dont understand your reaction. And you have not even reacted on my first comment.

Comment: What I am trying to ask with this question is that, is there a way to check if the permissions are allowed, if not then create the intent and ask for them with the line `new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")` etc. The device may or may not have the following permissions but thats what I am asking. How to check if it has the different permissions for the different SDK versions.

Comment: Please start with reacting to my first comment. You still did not. Forget my other comments for a while.

Comment: Well I was clarifyng that with the last comment but the permissions are first in Android 11 `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` or  `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` and for the lower versions `permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: No. `Environment.isExternalStorageManager()` is about `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` which you should 'request' in manifest file first. You did not even mention it. All the other things is how to obtain that permission at runtime .Switch it on/off at runtime and checking if it is on/off at runtime.

Comment: `but the permissions are first in Android 11 Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` That is no permission but an action. An action to let the user switch the permission for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on/off.

Comment: Alright, it is an action but how can you check if its permitted or not.

Comment: Environment.isExternalStorageManager() will tell you if 'all files access' is on/off.

Comment: That actually helped me figure it out, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for me here was to change `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q` to `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q` and then check permission with `!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    if(!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
} else {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if isExternalStorageManager() returns true you should give the user of your app the possibility to switch the permission off. Very usefull to test and examine behaviour with and without that permission. You should not compare MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE als they are different things. The  MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an extra above WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. And you also need the latter for 11+;

Comment: Added that too, thank you.